# yq select entry value based on subkey

Tags: yaml, yq

Using [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (v4.25.3), and considering the following yaml file

```
accounts:

- account_id: 'XXXXXXXX'
  name: sandbox
  deploy_iam: true
  role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/iam_role
  regions:
  - all

- account_id: 'YYYYYYY'
  name: dev
  deploy_iam: true
  role: arn:aws:iam::YYYYYYY:role/iam_role
  regions:
  - all
```

Is it possible to get the value of the `deploy_iam` attribute given an `account_id` value?

I can get the list of account_id with
`yq '.accounts[].account_id' < accounts.yml`

And I tried to filter using `with_entries`

```
 yq '.accounts[].account_id |= with_entries(select(.key == "XXXXXXXX"))' < accounts.yml
```

Without luck so far.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [mikfarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) it should be pretty straightforward. Select the required object with the `select()` expression and access the required field with the dot notation

```bash
yq '.accounts[] | select(.account_id == "XXXXXXXX").deploy_iam' < accounts.yml
```